# Easy way of knowing an availability of 64-bit version

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, 64-bit, 32-bit

My Question might bit odd to some, but is there any software that could let me know whether a 64 bit version of the software installed in my PC is available or not, instead of me going on each software vendor's website. As such i need to go to website to download the 64 bit version, but at least the checking could be done by software would be a great time saver.

Let me know if any query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Until Windows 8 comes out with its app store, I don't see any other way to do that checking than you mentioned - check each provider's website. Also, don't be surprised if many of them don't have 64-bit versions, as the existing 32-bit versions should work fine and a 64-bit conversion isn't always beneficial or worth the cost of whatever changed are needed.

Comment: There are update apps, such as Secunia PSI, but none that I am aware of offer availability checks for 64bit apps.